# Map function on object and get keys and values Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, dictionary, object

I have an object like this:

```
{"Job": "Electrician", "Starbucks": "Vanilla Frapaccino"}
```

I need to map over it to get the key and the value in a React component like this.

```
            return<DetailCell>
                <Label>{key}</Label>
                <Text style={TextStyle}>{value}</Text>
            </DetailCell>
```

map function says details says its undefined. If I do Object.keys(details) then I get the keys. How do I get both in React Native? Please help thanks.

Comment: If you have the key can also use `dataObject[key]` for the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns the array of key value pairs (`[[key1,value1],[key2,value2]..]` which you can `.map()` this way (using [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)):

```
const src = {"Job": "Electrician", "Starbucks": "Vanilla Frapaccino"}
...
Object.entries(src).map(([key,value]) => (
   <DetailCell>
      <Label>{key}</Label>
      <Text style={TextStyle}>{value}</Text>
   </DetailCell>
))
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks friend. I did entries but did not know I could nest the key value as the params.

Comment: @TylerNichol : you're most welcome, if your problem is solved now, you may accept the answer

Comment: @TylerNichol : and, by the way, what you call *nesting* is [destructuing assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) applied to the function arguments ;)